# How to restrict user access to only deployments via Capistrano? (deployment workflow issue)

Tags: security, deployment, ssh, capistrano

I look for good practices for deploying with capistrano.

I would like to start out with a short description how I used to do deployment.

capistrano is installed locally on a developer's computer. I deploy thought gateway with capistrano option `:gateway`. Firstly, I thought that with `:gateway` option I need to have ssh connection only to gateway host, but it turns out that I need ssh connection (*public key*) to all hosts where I want to deploy to.

I would like to find a convenient and secure way to deploy application.

For example, in case when new developer starts working, is much more convinient to put his *public_key* only on gateway server and not on all applications servers. On the other hand I don't want him to have any connection to servers in particular *ssh* to gateway, just because he is developer, he needs to do only deployments.

If you are aware of good practices for deploying with capistrano, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create special user accounts for every developer on the gateway machine as well as on the rest of the server machines. This you will have to do using the abilities your OS and ssh gives you. Make the developer accounts don't have the ability to login via a shell to the gateway etc.

I can't provide you with all the details, but I think I might have directed you in the right direction. You can ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) for the details how it is possible to allow an user to login and do only certain tasks on the server.

Digression/Opinion: It's better to have developers which you trust to do the deployments. If you do not trust a dev, better do not let him do crucial things like i.e. deployment to a production server.